# How to create multiple db schemas at runtime using JAVA?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So i have this pretty large project and i have to create database schemas at various points during runtime and also have connections to point to the newly created schemas. This might seem like havoc but the application is quite large,distributed and multi-agent, so each agent should take care of one such connection.

Again to state the question(s):

> 1) How can i create a schema at runtime?
>
> 2) Inside the java agent how to get the new connection string?

I've seen some examples that stated that i should instate a default connection, and change it at runtime using some method that i cannot seem to find now...

P.S. I'd prefer a JDBC solution for this problem :) but if there is an alternative i'd be glad to try it.

Comment: _Why_ do you need to create **schemas** at runtime?  Is this during the normal course of business?  Doing so requires certain privleges, which (if at **ALL** possible) you do **NOT** want to distribute access to - this is what install processes are for.

Comment: Well i need to automatically create schemas run some tests on them and drop them after the tests are done. The problem is that i know the schema that i need to create only when the user uploads the .sql file or some .xml file that has the schema description.

Comment: ... What kinds of tests are you planning on running?  In-memory databases are usually used for (at least initial) testing.  Although you may have a limited ability to verify the schema if it's being changed externally.

Comment: Well i have to run CRUD operations on the newly created schema :) and i also need to do some kind of stress testing on it. Oh and CRUD operations would be just a starting point, but it would suffice for now.

Comment: There are existing solutions for this type of thing (for the CRUD operations, at least); JUnit has connectors for databases/Spring which allow you to just wire it up.  Stress testing is more involved - you'd probably want to mimic an install process anyways.  If you just need to validate the functionality of your app, though, use an in-memory database, or just mock objects, and save yourself some hassle.

Comment: Well the point is that the schemas i want to create/load are not related to my app. The functionality the app provides is to run tests on those schemas, so would this require mimicking the install process?

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan If you have found the answer for your question, Can you please share it?  I also required to do the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on which database you are using. Creating schemas typically involves executing some DDL on a connection where you are logged in with appriopriate privilieges (create schema). On Oracle, you would do something like

```
connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY somepassword");
```

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm)

Connecting to the new schema (in Oracle, *user* is the same a *schema*) is just a matter of supplying the new users credentials when opening the connection.

In mysql, you would do something like

```
connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE test");
```

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html)

Connecting to the new schema (in MySQL, *database* = *schema*) you add the name of the database to the end of the connection url, like `mysql://myserver/test`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints provided, but they still won't solve my issue. I've added some comments to my main post about it.

Comment: Well then, what is your issue? I'm not going to write your application for you (I charge for those kinds of things ;) ). You're going to have to be a bit more specific about your problem. When I say specific, I don't mean post your detailed requirements analysis, I mean what code/tech have you tried, and what problems did you run into?

Comment: Please read the comments of my questions, i guess those will provide sufficient information about what i need to do. I don't need code for it, just the part that loads the newly created schema.

Comment: Not sure what "load the newly created schema" means, but I have provided information how to both create and connect to a new schema in mysql and oracle (you didn't specify database so it's hard to be more specific). What else is it you are wondering about?

Comment: well since my question might not have been very straight forward i'll accept your answer and come back later with a proper example of how i stand with my problem. thank you